# Easyadmin bundle of Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony4, easyadmin

I am creating backend using Symfony. I want to create submenu. I am writing following code in easy_admin file inside config/packages:

```
easy_admin:
    design:
        menu:
            - label: 'Products'
              icon: 'shopping-basket'
              children:
                  - { entity: 'Product', icon: 'th-list', label: 'List Products' }
                  - { entity: 'Product', label: 'Add Product' }
                  - { label: 'Additional Items' }
                  - { entity: 'User', label: 'Users' }
```

I have created entities of `Product` and `User` located in `src/Entity`

But I am getting error:

> The "Product" entity included in the "menu" option is not managed by
>   EasyAdmin. The menu can only include any of these entities: .

What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you need at first read carefully the documentation on [easyadmin](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/your-first-backend.html). Then you find there that you need to add your entities to easyadmin config file, smth like this:

```
# config/packages/easy_admin.yaml
easy_admin:
# ...
    entities:
        - App\Entity\Product
        - App\Entity\User
```

or

```
# config/packages/easy_admin.yaml
easy_admin:
# ...
    entities:
        Product:
            class: App\Entity\Product
        User:
            class: App\Entity\User
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I got it.

Comment: I am trying to create 3 level sub-menu in Symfony. Is it possible to create it?

Comment: @JaveriaShabbir, glad to be helpful. Please mark the answer as accepted, if it answers your question. As far as I know easyadmin doesn't support three-level menus.